# How do I know what dependencies I can inject into a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller, angularjs-provider

I am trying to use `$routeProvider` dependency inside my controller:

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $state, $routeProvider) {
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProviderProvider <- $routeProvider
```

How do I know what dependencies I can inject into any given controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two phases inside angular

1. Configuration Phase (Here we use `app.config` to write a code)
2. Run phase (Where we use `app.run`, after run cycle all other directives gets executed using compile cycle)

Provider is nothing but service/factory but the most important thing is it can be accessible inside configuration phase.

**Example**

Suppose we have below provider

```
myApp.provider('unicornLauncher', function UnicornLauncherProvider() {
    var useTinfoilShielding = false;

    this.useTinfoilShielding = function(value) {
        useTinfoilShielding = !!value;
    };

    this.$get = ["apiToken", function unicornLauncherFactory(apiToken) {
        return new UnicornLauncher(apiToken, useTinfoilShielding);
    }];
});
```

While inject it inside config you should always prefix it `Provider` like `unicornLauncherProvider`

While using it inside controller you could use it as `unicornLauncher`

**Note:**

> **Provider** are always accessible inside `.config`(**configuration**)
>   phase with suffix `Provider` in their name, While inside controller you could > directly inject it using `unicornLauncher` (direct provider name)
>
> **Services/Factory** They are not visible in config phase of angular

Still confuse then do refer [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory/28262966#28262966)

Answer (score 2):

You can only access services in the controller not the providers so use `$route` here.

Therefore you are getting error **$routeProviderProvider** becuase it is looking for the provider for `$routeProvider` which is itself a provider for `$route`.

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)